# Style for custom control inheriting a base control is not applied (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF project, I have an 'ExtendedButton' UserControl which inherits from Button, and overrides the control template of the button to add things like a Border, allowing for easy addition of rounded corners. I like keeping this fairly generic so as it is, it still looks fairly plain.

In a project using the project above, in the App.xaml I have created a style with a custom key, and a target type of this 'ExtendedButton'. In a control in this project I have added an 'ExtendedButton' and set its style explicitly to the style mentioned above. It appears to have reverted to the style of the base of the 'ExtendedButton', a key symptom of this being setting width etc works, but the corner radius property, while recognised, is not applied.

I've tried setting the control template in my style, which correctly adds properties like the corner radius, but doesn't allow for any customisation in my control where the button is placed. No matter what I do it seems to revert to being a base button.

An MWE of the setup described above:
The button:
ExtendedButton.xaml:

```
<Button
    x:Class="Win10Themables.Controls.ExtendedButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Win10Themables.Controls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="buttonExtension"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Button.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383" />
    </Button.Resources>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ThemableFocusStyle}" />
            <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border
                            x:Name="border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="{Binding Path=CornerRadius, ElementName=buttonExtension}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Focusable="False"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

ExtendedButton.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Win10Themables.Controls
{
    public partial class ExtendedButton : Button
    {
        public ExtendedButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public CornerRadius CornerRadius
        {
            get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(ExtendedButton), new PropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(0)));
    }
}
```

The style:

```
<Application
    x:Class="Application"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Win10Themables.Controls;assembly=Win10Themables"
    xmlns:svgc="http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/svgc/">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Style x:Key="RoundButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type controls:ExtendedButton}">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10" />
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

A control with the button and style applied:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="UserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Win10Themables.Controls;assembly=Win10Themables"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <controls:ExtendedButton
            Style="{StaticResource RoundButtonStyle}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        </controls:ExtendedButton>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for the different ways to create custom controls. A derived Button like this would usually be created as a custom control with a default Style in Themes/Generic.xaml. You can create it in Visual Studio by adding a *Custom Control* instead of a *User Control*.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I'll take a look and give your suggested approach a go

Answer (score 0):

Your custom control has no *default* style and that's why it doesn't behave as you would expect.

`ExtendedButton` should be defined as a standalone class including a static constructor but no XAML file:

```
public class ExtendedButton : Button
{
    static ExtendedButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExtendedButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ExtendedButton)));
    }

    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(ExtendedButton), new PropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(0)));
}
```

You should then define the default `Style` for it in a `ResourceDictionary` named `generic.xaml` located in a `themes` folder at the root of the project:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ExtendedButton}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ThemableFocusStyle}" />
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`themes/generic.xaml` is a naming convention. WPF will look for the default template in this exact location.

Comment: @JosephWard: Does this answer your question? What's your current issue?